Nucleophilicity of anions associated with organic cations
I was wondering whether there were any general rules / papers that describe factors that affect the nucleophilicity of an anion when comparing organic cations. For example, if I was comparing triethylammonium chloride and pyridinium chloride, which chloride would be more nucleophilic in a polar solvent?
I know that triethylamine is a stronger base than that of pyridine, but here it would be triethylammonium cation and pyridinium cation. Does the strength of the ionic interaction between the organic cation and the halide affect the nucleophilicity of the chloride anion?

Huh, nucleophilicity of counterion in ammonium halides isn't something you ponder everyday. Unless the solvent and reagents would have very little basicity, it would still be amine being the most important nucleophile.

What if I was doing an SN2 though? Surely the anion is important to consider more so than the cation?
